# Accessing elements in json object in mongodb shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I can't understand but from some reason when
I get the results into a variable I can't access them
like any other json object.

For example:

```
db.students.find('', {name:1}).limit(1)
```

Gives:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("611cf54c6ed92c90105f7ce8"), name: 'Ofek' }
```

But when I get the results into this variable like this

```
let testRes = db.students.find('', {name:1}).limit(1)
```

And then print out name:

```
console.log(testRes.name)
```

Nothing printed out.

But when I create a variable manually like that:

```
let testJson = { _id: ObjectId("611cf54c6ed92c90105f7ce8"), name: 'Ofek' }
```

I can access the json object without problems

```
console.log(testJson.name)
```

Output:

```
'Ofek'
```

Why can't I access the Json object?

Comment: `db.students.find` returns a cursor, not a document.

Comment: Yea now I got it ty!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround.
Preety sure though it's not the best practice:

```
db.students.aggregate([
        { $limit: 1}
    ]).toArray()[0].name
```

It works though.

Update:
I found out I needed to use findOne instead of find.

Answer (score 0):

Methods like `find` and `limit` return a cursor, not a list or a document (even if the cursor results *do* get rendered as such in the mongo shell).

If you want to convert the cursor results into an array (or you want the first result as a document object) you can call `cursor.toArray()` or `cursor.tryNext()` (docs [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/)).

In reference to your example, you can do the following:

```
let testRes = db.students.find('', {name:1}).limit(1).tryNext()
```